# Cointegrating vectors/equations

Tags: r, time-series, cointegration, vector-autoregression, vector-error-correction-model

I am experimenting with 5 variable co-integration model via simulations. Below are output of cointegrating vectors from two different data sets. As you can see there are 4 long run equations in each output. I want to use the coefficients of the first equation which is labelled as `ecm1` for economic inference i.e. interpret individual coefficients as the equation is normalized on the first variable `x1` as I wanted. What I do not understand is this: The `ecm1` equation, in Output 1, has non-zero parameter values (coefficients) but the Output 2 `ecm1` equation has one zero coefficient. That is, the coefficient of `x2` is zero. Please note, no restrictions imposed on the parameters.

Output 1

```
            ecm1        ecm2          ecm3          ecm4
x1     1.000000e+00 -5.551115e-17 -4.440892e-16  0.000000e+00
x2    -1.249001e-16  1.000000e+00 -2.775558e-16  0.000000e+00
x3    -1.387779e-17  0.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  2.775558e-17
x4     8.326673e-17  0.000000e+00  2.220446e-16  1.000000e+00
x5     2.328343e-01  1.420360e-01  4.755383e-01 -5.795120e-02
trend -9.906519e-03  5.355792e-03  9.544451e-03  1.080801e-02
```

Output 2

```
             ecm1        ecm2          ecm3          ecm4
X1     1.000000e+00 -2.081668e-17 -7.494005e-16 -1.110223e-16
X2     0.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
X3    -2.775558e-17 -1.040834e-17  1.000000e+00 -2.775558e-17
X4     2.220446e-16 -2.775558e-17 -2.220446e-16  1.000000e+00
X5     3.413323e-01  3.521056e-01  1.156258e+00  2.731349e-01
trend -3.937624e-03  1.041338e-02  2.355562e-02  1.619330e-02
```

Can anyone provide a plausible explanation to this puzzle I am facing? 
Thanks

Comment: Could you provide more details on your simulation design?

Comment: @RichardHardy, I take 5 variable randomly simulated data set and estimate a VECM. The data is created such that there are 4 cointegrating vectors. The above output, just confirms this, though, what I am confused about is the 0 coefficicient value for X2 in the second output. I expect it to be a negative non-zero value.

Comment: This is still not detailed enough. Without seeing the code it is difficult to tell the problem. Also, note that many of the other coefficients are very close to zero (have `e-16` or `e-17` at the end).

Comment: Yeah, I just figured out why I have zeros there, this is because the default restriction on cointegrating equations is an identity matrix. Therefore, there is a clear zero and then near zero coefficients. Though, they should not be near zero, should be clear zero. Just see the pattern of ones on 4x4 matrix, they are on the diagonal.

Comment: That just seems like a numerical issue of no practical implication. Since you can only estimate the cointegrating space (that is, any relation which lives in this space can be used, there is no unique equation) it is customary to normalize with an identity matrix in the upper part of the beta matrix.

Comment: Yep, that's what i figured out after posting the question.